What are those stuck ssh processes after accessing file server in Caja
I regularly access some remote file server in Caja from remote locations where I don't have a vpn set up. I assume most users of this platform are familiar with that.

Whenever the network connection is lost or the laptop is put into hibernate mode without unmounting the file server, there are some leftovers of those ssh connections which also cause several parts of the KDE desktop to get stuck.
When that happens, the KDE panel is usually frozen, so I cannot click on its "Networks" icon to reconnect or to connect to another network after changing locations.
The Caja filemanager window is obviously frozen as well. And in some cases, save file dialogs won't open, for example, if you'd want to download a pdf file in the browser, that browser would also get stuck waiting for KDE to display the save file dialog.
I've noticed there's always a pair of ssh processes and when I kill either of them, the KDE desktop becomes usable again:
$ pgrep -a ssh
456167 ssh -oForwardX11 no -oForwardAgent no -oPermitLocalCommand no -oClearAllForwardings yes -oProtocol 2 -oNoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost yes -oControlMaster auto -oControlPath=/run/user/1000/gvfsd-sftp/%C -s server sftp
456214 ssh -oForwardX11 no -oForwardAgent no -oPermitLocalCommand no -oClearAllForwardings yes -oProtocol 2 -oNoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost yes -oControlMaster auto -oControlPath=/run/user/1000/gvfsd-sftp/%C -s server sftp

How are these controlled? I would rather not manually find and kill them.
In the example, their parent is 2599, which appears to be systemd:
$ ps -fp 2599
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
user        2599       1  0 Apr08 ?        00:01:46 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user


In extreme cases, the lock screen is also stuck, forcing me to kill it from a tty using pkill -9 kscreenlocker, but I think this may happen when an external monitor is missing after restoring from hibernate mode, not sure if stuck ssh connections alone also play into that.
It happens on different systems and it's not at all new, but this is now on Fedora, with plasmashell 5.27.11.
